# How to share a variable between two python scripts run separately

Tags: python, arrays, variables

I'm an extreme noob to python, so If there's a better way to do what I'm asking please let me know.

I have one file, which works with flask to create markers on a map. It has an array which stores these said markers. I'm starting the file through command prompt, and opening said file multiple times. Basically, how would one open a file multiple times, and have them share a variable (Not the same as having a subfile that shares variables with a superfile.) I'm okay with creating another file that starts the instances if needed, but I'm not sure how I'd do that.

Here is an example of what I'd like to accomplish. I have a file called, let's 
say, test.py:

```
global number
number += 1
print(number)
```

I'd like it so that when I start this through command prompt (python test.py) multiple times, it'd print the following:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

The only difference between above and what I have, is that what I have will be non-terminating and continuously running

Comment: You should read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and write up a [MCVE] outlining what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you seem to be looking for is some form of inter-process communication. In terms of python, each process has its own memory space and its own variables meaning that if I ran.

```
number += 1
print(number)
```

Multiple times then I would get 1,2..5 on a new line. No matter how many times I start the script, number would be a global.

There are a few ways where you can keep consistency.

## **Writing To A File (named pipe)**

One of your scripts can have (generator.py)

```
import os
num = 1
try:
    os.mkfifo("temp.txt")
except:
    pass # In case one of your other files already started
while True:
    file = open("temp.txt", "w")
    file.write(num)
    file.close() # Important because if you don't close the file
    # The operating system will lock your file and your other scripts
    # Won't have access

    sleep(# seconds)
```

In your other scripts (consumer.py)

```
while True:
    file = open("temp.txt", "r")
    number = int(file.read())
    print(number)
    sleep(# seconds)
```

You would start 1 or so generator and as many consumers as you want. Note: this does have a race condition that can't really be avoided. When you write to the file, you should use a serializer like pickler or json to properly encode and decode your array object.

### Other Ways

You can also look up how to use pipes (both named and unnamed), databases, ampq (IMHO the best way to do it but there is a learning curve and added dependencies), and if you are feeling bold use mmap.

### Design Change

If you are willing to listen to a design change, Since you are making a flask application that has the variable in memory why don't you just make an endpoint to serve up your array and check the endpoint every so often?

```
 import json # or pickle
 import flask

 app = Flask(__name__)
 array = [objects]
 converted = method_to_convert_to_array_of_dicts(array)
 @app.route("/array")
 def hello():
     return json.dumps(array)
```

You will need to convert but then the web server can be hosted and your clients would just need something like

```
import requests
import json

while True:
    result = requests.get('localhost/array')
    array = json.loads(str(result.body)) # or some string form of result
    sleep(...)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your description is kind of confusing, but if I understand you correctly, one way of doing this would be to keep the value of the variable in a separate file.

When a script needs the value, read the value from the file and add one to it.  If the file doesn't exist, use a default value of 1.  Finally, rewrite the file with the new value.

However you said that this value would be shared among two python scripts, so you'd have to be careful that both scripts don't try to access the file at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use `pickle.dump(your array, file)` to serie the data(your array) intoto a file. And at next time running the script, you could just load the data back with `pickle.dump(your array, file)`